# Generating code first poco classes from existing database does not generate indexes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and I am trying to generate code-first POCO classes from that database using VS 2017 as following:

[image: Ado.net data model]

But when it generates them I cannot see indexes.

Is there any way I can get them generated as index attribute?

Comment: Because you're using Database First approach, **it is not relevant to add the index attribute to your entity**. 

This attribute is relevant only when database need to be generated.

Comment: do you try [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator) ?

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh I have tried it but it does not generate index attributes for unique and non-clustered indexes . Could you please help me out configure it to do that?

Comment: i did search and research for this issue but don't find any answer to resolve this. you just can create index with attribute or fluent-api manually. also i find this [issue](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/issues/56) in EF POCO Generator repo. if you need help to create index with fluent-api just tell me;